# Training a NN , first epoch takes 90secs and after that all the epochs take like 2-5 mins per epoch is this normal

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, model

So I am have tried different different nn and dataset but the problem arise is that first epoch takes way less time as compared to others like
first will take 90sec and 2 to limit will take 3-5mins per epoch is this normal or something wrong with the device or software
i am using gtx 1060maxq on i7 8750h
on tensorflow-gpu 2.4.1 and keras-gpu wit cudnn 10.ver something
[image]

```
model= tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=True, classes=1, weights=None)
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy import sparse
train_x = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_x)
train_y = tf.convert_to_tensor(train_y)
model.fit(train_x,train_y,epochs= 10 , batch_size =32)
```

Comment: You should at least provide the code you are trying to execute. Try to post a minimal reproductive example.

Comment: i have edited the post can you check?

Comment: single label should have a `loss='binary_crossentropy'`